# How to build an active record association between three models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to model an application for physicians and am stuck wrapping my head around the db design. Let's assume that a user can create a case, which can be associated to symptoms, diagnoses and therapies. This doesn't sound too hard in the first place.

However, I need the physician to provide the diagnosis from a given table which includes all known diagnoses (seeded by an admin). Furthermore, one diagnosis can have many therapies, while the physician should choose one for that particular case (again all possible therapies are seeded by an admin).

I haven't started actually coding the application but I've created a [db diagram](https://dbdiagram.io/d/5d6f826383427516dc0b5226). The best I could think of so far is to associate `cases` and `diagnoses` through `has_and_belongs_to`. This doesn't seem to be optimal either as a case can only have one diagnosis. 
Anyway, I'm really not quite sure what to do with `therapies` as a case only `has_one` therapy and a diagnosis can `has_many` therapies.

I also thought about working with jsonb columns, but I would rather stick to a relational approach.

Any input on this is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a model that supports the following logic:

- a case can only have one diagnosis

  - a diagnosis can be picked from a list of options
  - a diagnosis can have many therapies
- a case can only have one therapy

If that's correct, then what you have so far looks pretty good.  A few comments / questions:

1. If you can only have one diagnosis per case, why not just include `diagnosis_id` as an attribute in the `cases` table?  Unless you need to specifically track any other data between the case-diagnosis relationship (which you aren't doing right now), you don't need a separate table.  This could potentially speed up your queries by cutting out an additional `JOIN`.  If think down the line it might change, then you can leave it as a separate table.
2. If a case can only have one therapy, again you can just include this as an attribute in the `cases` table.  See the logic in #1.
3. When you say a diagnosis can have many therapies, do you mean that the user will assign one or more therapies to a diagnosis?  If that's the case, then just create a new table called `case_diagnosis_therapy` where you can track this.  The relationship between a case's diagnosis and its therapies would be through `(case_id, diagnosis_id)`.  You already have the `diagnoses` lookup table.
4. And yes, I agree that you are better suited to stick with a relational design instead of JSON.  Your model looks pretty structured.
5. Just a suggestion for conventions, when you make your table names usually you use singular names - `case` instead of `cases`.

Just a few things to think about, otherwise it looks pretty good!  Hope that helps.

Comment: Mmm in rails (and in my long-standing experience in general) table-names are usually plural (as the table contains multiple rows), but YMMV, but it in the rails-world at least this is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, a case

- has-many :images
- has-many :symptoms
- has-many diagnoses from a fixed list of possible diagnoses, which you solved correctly. My only remark would be to call the reference `diagnose_id` (from the `case_diagnoses` table)

The only thing missing is the `therapies` associations. I see two possible options:

- a therapy is always linked to a single diagnoses
- a therapy could be linked to multiple diagnoses

E.g. for a fever and a sprained ankle, the therapy could both be "cooling", or they could be much more specific (and more diagnoses related). So that is unclear.

So if a therapy is always linked to a single diagnoses:

- therapy belongs-to diagnose
- a case has-many case-therapies
- and case-therapy belongs_to therapy

If a therapy can belong to multiple diagnoses, you just have to add a inbetween link table

- diagnose-therapies belongs-to therapy and diagnose

... and the rest stays the same.

(oh and thank you for sharing the dbdiagram.io platform, I had never heard of it before, it looks amazing!)